# How to install Scala software

Tags: scala

I want to use a tool written by Scala but I have no experience with Scala.

The tool  I want to use is from https://github.com/allenai/pdffigures2. It told me how to install the tool in the readme but I can not understand.

It said I need

```
     resolvers += Resolver.bintrayRepo("allenai", "maven")
```

And then include

```
      libraryDependencies += "org.allenai" %% "pdffigures2" % "0.0.11"
```

what does that mean, where should I add them? I am on Ubuntu. It would be kind if someone can tell me how to install this tool step by step, currently, there is not Scala in my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install sbt (Scala build tool) from here: http://www.scala-sbt.org/

Create a new Project with

```
sbt new scala/scala-seed.g8
cd <project_name>
vi build.sbt
```

Add your lines to this build.sbt. After that you can use the commands given in the section "Command Line Tools" of pdffigures2

Edit: Just saw that the library is only available for Scala 2.11. Could you change the scala version in build.sbt as follows:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.11",
```

Comment: You answer works. But another issue comes: I have added  resolvers += Resolver.bintrayRepo("allenai", "maven")  to the build.sbt  according to the readme file, but it also told me 
  "unresolved dependency: org.allenai#pdffigures2_2.12;0.0.11: not found ". Could you tell me how fix it?

Comment: The library is only available for scala 2.11, I edited the answer to show how to specify the version number.